# Why is Cyborg in Doom Patrol instead of Titans?

Tags: character, production, titans, doom-patrol

I recently started watching DC Universe show *Titans* and realized Cyborg was not there but he is apparently in the spinoff *Doom Patrol* in a prominent role. But why this change?

*Titans* is based on comic books team *Teen Titans* and Cyborg was a famous part of it but he was not in *Doom Patrol* comics. So why did they make this change? Any official words for this decision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/cyborg-doom-patrol-tv-show-not-comics/) explains the change and connections, suggesting that Cyborg fits thematically in couple of ways, is connected to *Doom Patrol* in a secondary way, and believes his presence will help attract viewers.

> ...**While Victor Stone was never a part of the Doom Patrol in any comic
>   book series, he would be a perfect fit for the team thematically.**
>   **Every member of the classic Doom Patrol had their life endangered by a
>   horrible accident and was saved only by an experimental treatment
>   conceived by Dr. Niles Caulder.** It could be argued, however, that
>   death would have been preferable to Dr. Caulder's cures, which left
>   his patients as something both more and less than human and often
>   wishing that they had been allowed to die. This was the exact same
>   state that young Victor Stone was in immediately following his
>   father's efforts to save his life.
>
> Though Cyborg was created nearly two decades after the first Doom
>   Patrol comics were published, **his origin story fit the same tragic
>   mold as Elasti-Woman and Negative Man. The body horror parallels are
>   particularly strong between Cyborg and Robotman,** whose brain was
>   transplanted into a super-strong and almost unbreakable robot body
>   that was also incapable of smelling, tasting or any fine sense of
>   touch. Given that, **it is surprising that a connection between Cyborg
>   and the Doom Patrol has never been established before now. This seems
>   particularly strange given that Cyborg's closest friend in the comics,
>   Beast Boy, was a member of the Doom Patrol before he joined the New
>   Teen Titans.**
>
> **Beyond the thematic connections, Cyborg's induction into the Doom
>   Patrol will also serve to attract casual comics fans to the new series
>   and offer them an accessible frame of reference.**

And to help confirm Screenrant's assessment, actor [Joivain Wade](https://www.dccomics.com/blog/2019/02/22/why-joivan-wades-cyborg-debuts-on-doom-patrol-instead-of-titans) (Cyborg) basically says nearly the same thing, but with the notion that *maybe this is how Cyborg becomes the character he is in *Teen Titans*, *should that be DC TV series' plan...

> "**Every single person in the Doom Patrol has gone through traumatic,
>   unfortunate events which have given them some kind of dysfunction or
>   disability,**" Wade says. "Vic has turned his into something good,
>   whereas the rest of the guys are essentially learning how to turn
>   theirs into something good. **But when it comes to him learning and
>   growing and becoming who he's meant to be, who better to learn from
>   than a bunch of characters who have also gone through similar things?
>   It's been a greater playground for him to be discovering and learning
>   about himself to then be ready to join the Titans when the DCU decides
>   to do that."**